# Need help to fix shell script to convert string to json response

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I am trying to convert below string which is stored inside a txt file into json formatted string

```
High Severity Results: 0
Medium Severity Results: 1
Low Severity Results: 2
Information Severity Results: 0
Scan Results Location: Https://www.checkmarx.abc.com/cxwebclient/viewermain.aspx?scanid=12345&projectid=1234
```

to below json format

```
{
"High Severity Results" : "0",
"Medium Severity Results" : "1",
"Low Severity Results" : "2",
"Information Severity Results" : "0",
"Scan Results Location" : "Https://www.checkmarx.abc.com/cxwebclient/viewermain.aspx?scanid=12345&projectid=1234",
}
```

I tried the below command.

```
file="Checkmarx_Json_Data.txt"
checkmarxDataNew="$(cat Checkmarx_Json_Data.txt)"
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  for val in $line
  do
    echo "\"${val//:/\":\"}\"" >> ACM_BQ_JSON_Response.json
  done
done < "$file"
```

but the above script is generating response in below format

```
"checkmarx" : {
"High"
"Severity"
"Results":""
"0"
"Medium"
"Severity"
"Results":""
"1"
"Low"
"Severity"
"Results":""
"2"
"Information"
"Severity"
"Results":""
"0"
"Scan"
"Results"
"Location":""
"Https":"//www.checkmarx.ford.com/cxwebclient/viewermain.aspx?scanid=2500093&projectid=28069"
}
```

when I tried with a Single string like color:red, it worked well.

can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it can be done with `jq`:

```bash
jq --raw-input 'split("\\s*:\\s*"; "") | 
  { (.[0]): (.[1:] | join(":")) }' < input-file | \
jq --slurp add
```

output:

```json
{
  "High Severity Results": "0",
  "Medium Severity Results": "1",
  "Low Severity Results": "2",
  "Information Severity Results": "0",
  "Scan Results Location": "Https://www.checkmarx.abc.com/cxwebclient/viewermain.aspx?scanid=12345&projectid=1234"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ee 's/$/,/;1i\{' -e '$a\}' -e 's/^([^:]*)(: )([^,]*)/"\1" \2"\3"/' Checkmarx_Json_Data.txt
{
"High Severity Results" : "0",
"Medium Severity Results" : "1",
"Low Severity Results" : "2",
"Information Severity Results" : "0",
"Scan Results Location" : "Https://www.checkmarx.abc.com/cxwebclient/viewermain.aspx?scanid=12345&projectid=1234",
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick solution, it has parsed the string but I see the comma(,) is getting added only in the last line which is not needed rather it should be added at end of all other lines

`
{
"High Severity Results" : "0",
"Medium Severity Results" : "1",
"Low Severity Results" : "2",
"Information Severity Results" : "0",
"Scan Results Location" : "Https://www.checkmarx.abc.com/cxwebclient/viewermain.aspx?scanid=12345&projectid=1234"
}
`

Comment: @KarthikPeddineni Apologies for missing that. Please check edit.

Comment: To be valid JSON, the last line (and _only_ the last line) shouldn't have a comma. BTW, this is part of why using a tool like `jq` that actually understands JSON is _by far_ the better approach -- trying to implement full/proper escaping (which would mean, f/e, changing `"`s in the data to `\"` sequences and handling a bunch of other characters that need escaping in a separate way as well).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

total_cnt=$(wc -l < Checkmarx_Json_Data.txt)

{
printf {\\n
while IFS= read -r line; do
  col1=${line%%:*}
  col2=${line#*: }
  if ((++line_cnt < total_cnt)); then
    printf '  "%s" : "%s",\n' "$col1" "$col2"
  else
    printf '  "%s" : "%s"\n' "$col1" "$col2"
  fi
done < Checkmarx_Json_Data.txt
printf }
} > ACM_BQ_JSON_Response.json
```

---

If `ed` is available/acceptable, something like:

The `script.ed` (name it to your own hearts content)

```
,s/\([^:]*\)\(: \)\(.*\)/  "\1" \2"\3"/
1,$-1s/$/,/
0a
{
.
$a
}
.
,p
Q
```

---

Now run:

```
ed -s Checkmarx_Json_Data.txt < script.ed
```

To create a new file with the edited output,

```
ed -s Checkmarx_Json_Data.txt < script.ed > ACM_BQ_JSON_Response.json
```